# Regular expression for letters and some characters

Tags: regex

Hi I have a regular expression which allows only letters and some characters (.-) and whitespace. The problem is that I want it to pass even when the textfield is empty. The \s requires a space, which is fine, but I want it to pass without any keyboard input as well. Here it is:

```
^[\sA-Za-z.-]+$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `+` quantifier to `*`, and you are done: -

```
^[\sA-Za-z.-]*$
```

It will match `0 or more` occurrences. And `0` occurrence will mean empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be a * (0 or more) instead of a + (1 or more)

```
^[\sA-Za-z.-]*$
```